# Expresscard Not Detected in PCI-E Adapter

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, pci-express, expresscard

I'm trying to put an expresscard TV tuner (Avermedia HC82) into my HTPC using this [expresscard to PCI-E adapter](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16815124043).  I've verified that the tuner works fine in my laptop.  The motherboard is a Biostar TF7050-M2.  When I install it and turn it on, the light on the back of the adapter comes on fine (there are two indicator lights on the back to show if it is using PCI-E or USB communication, USB communication goes through a USB cable connected between the card and a header on the motherboard) showing that it is working in PCI-E mode.

However, the device is never detected in Windows 7 Professional x64.  The auto detect never happens, it doesn't show up in the device manager, and I can have it rescan for new hardware and nothing is found.  I tested the whole setup (tuner + adapter) in another PC (also using Win 7 Pro x64) and it worked fine.

I also tried:

- Plugging the adapter in to the PCI-E x16 slot on the motherboard (I verified first that the x16 slot worked by installing a video card in it)
- Booting into safe mode and rescanning
- Updating the chipset drivers
- Installing the tuner drivers first
- Using a different USB cable, plugged in to one of the known good ports on the back of the board
- Trying it without the USB cable plugged in
- Removing the other PCI cards that were installed on the board
- Looking through the BIOS for any setting that might be disabling it somehow

to no avail.

I'm at a loss for what else to try.  I really don't want to RMA it (the shipping back to newegg will be almost as much as it cost to buy in the first place.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There are no extra drivers need for windows 7 x64. It will automatically install drivers for it. You just check about the hardware installation first and then other stuff.

> First of all make sure that you connect the included cable to the USB Type-B port
>   on the device, and the other end to a motherboard internal USB header.

I have read some statements about the usage of this device in Windows 7, the all telling that it works fine with Windows 7.. Check this [here](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16815124043).